# Sencha touch 2 SDK compress JS file

Tags: compression, sencha-touch

there is a way to specify in app.json, where I include js files, not to minify 1 js file, somethig like

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "sdk/sencha-touch.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "sdk/myjs.js",
        "compress": false
    },
...


"compress": false --  ofc doesn work , there is something to specify not to compress or minify that js file ?
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fas as I found there is not why to specify not to compress, the way how I do an workaround is:

1. creating in "resources" folder a "js" folder and dropped my js file in that folder
2. Updated the `app.json` file (not to loose the "js" folder when we build production app) like this :

   ```
   "resources": [
       "resources/js",
   ]
   ```
3. Include the file in index html  as a regular script